# Opensource Puppet Master Setup Issue causing unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet

Tags: puppet

I have to give up using PE to set up my puppet master :( and I have been throw in the cold cruel Opensource Puppet world.
I have been trying to set up a opensource puppet master on a RHEL7 system.  I am planning to do this a couple of times so wrote a very simple shell script. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

pc_rpm_name='puppetlabs-release-pc1'
pc_yum_repo_url="https://yum.puppetlabs.com/${pc_rpm_name}-el-7.noarch.rpm"

# set up puppet collection yum repo
rpm -Uvh $pc_yum_repo_url
yum -y install puppetserver
systemctl start puppetserver
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module install puppetlabs-puppetdb --version 5.1.2
```

I have a puppet master puppet class I wrote it is very simple:

```
class my_puppetmaster {
    class { 'puppetdb': listen_address => %{::fqdn} }" 
    include puppetdb::master::config
}
```

I want to use hiera for my node classification so I have done this:

```
# pwd
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
# cat site.pp 
hiera_include('classes')
```

I have also created this file:

```
# pwd
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/nodes
# cat puppet_master.yaml 
classes:
  - my_puppetmaster
```

And here is my hiera.yaml file:

```
# pwd
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet
# head hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "nodes/%{::role}"
...
```

I haven't gotten around to set up a custom fact yet.  I figure I could testing out at the point by rebooting the system to give everything a good shake out and then running `puppet agent -t` and see what happens.  When I run `puppet agent -t` on the puppet master I get this output:

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppet]
```

I guess I left something out of my set up script.  So ... what did I miss?

Thanks
Red

Comment: I forgot to update my puppet.conf. I had "server = puppet" I need to change that to "server = fqdn of my puppet master"

Comment: you should add that comment as an answer to your own question; it solved the problem for me, at any rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to update my puppet.conf. I had "server = puppet" I need to change that to "server = fqdn of my puppet master"

Comment: ON WHICH MACHINE?

Comment: I updated the puppet.conf on the system where I was running `puppet agent -t`, which in this case just happened to the be the puppet master.